# EF Core Linq changing int value zero to -2147482646

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-3.1

I am using EFCore with Linq to Sql. The table only contains two columns, VolunteerId and RoleId. My Linq is:

```
        VolunteerRole vr = new VolunteerRole();
        vr.RoleId = 9;
        vr.VolunteerId = 0;
        _db.VolunteerRoles.Add(vr);

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Nothing special about the linq. However, when tracing in SQL server, the actual sql statement generated was:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;INSERT INTO [VolunteerRole] ([VolunteerId], [RoleId]) VALUES (@p0, @p1);',N'@p0 int,@p1 tinyint',@p0=-2147482646,@p1=9
```

So for some reason, somewhere, the int value "0" was changed to "-2147482646". I assume this is the int.MinValue? But why? Why can't I simply set a int to 0, which is a valid value in my db?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at that column in the database? Is it an identity column? How is it defined?

Comment: It is not `int.MinValue`, which is `-2147483648`

Comment: No, it's not an identify column, it's foreign key to Volunteer table by VolunteerId. Two columns together forms Primary Key.

Comment: That appears to be a value that the change tracker assigns before trying to generate a new value (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14085)). I haven't tried it, but it might bypass that if you [disable value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#no-value-generation-1) for that field

Comment: Why do you want to assign `0` to a foreign key value? I think that's the first thing to question here.

Comment: The primary key value is indeed 0. I think that's the problem. It was transferred over from a legacy system and there is a default account that has a primary key of 0. Not much I could do. Lesson learned -- primary key should never be 0!